# How do I loop the output of 5 different inputs? I want to get the output looped so that 5 sets come out

Tags: javascript, html, loops

How do I loop the output of 5 different inputs? I want to get the output looped so that 5 sets come out.
This is what i have tried:
I'm trying to loop this section along with my other 4 sections of user inputs.

```
 <input id="myInput" type="text">
 




 <button onclick="myFunction()">See your trip</button>

 <p id="output1"></p>


 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 A = 0;
 B = 450;
 C = 590;
 D = 710;
 E = 1030;
 F = 1280;
 G = 1360;
 var startDistance;
 var inputLine = document.getElementById("myInput").value;


  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  switch(inputLine[0]) {
  case "A":
    startDistance = A;
    break;
   case "B":
    startDistance = B;
  break;

case "C":
startDistance = C;
break;
```

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=` so you append to the string instead of replacing.

Comment: ^ in the loop, not on the final assignment

Comment: Ok I did that and 5 sets came out which is great! However, I want 5 different sets to come out based on the users input. How can I do this?

Comment: Retrieve user inputs ***inside*** the loop,

Comment: I want to do that but I used switch statements for 4 of my inputs and 1 one of my inputs just took it straight from the input. How would I do that?

Comment: Your question doesn't have a switch of any sort.  You are finding issues with code you have not shown us.  *Show us*

Comment: How am I supposed to add more code now? Should I make a new post?

Comment: Bottom left of the body of your post there is an "edit" button between the "share" and "follow" buttons

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters... it appears that your code isn't formatted correctly, provided that you just didn't show all of it, which looks to be the case.

There is also this weird snippet `inputLine[0]`... is there an input that is holding an array as a value?

```
function myFunction()
{
    A = 0;
    B = 450;
    C = 590;
    D = 710;
    E = 1030;
    F = 1280;
    G = 1360;
    var startDistance;
    var inputLine = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        switch(inputLine[0])
        {
            case "A":
                startDistance = A;
                break;
            case "B":
                startDistance = B;
                break;
            case "C":
                startDistance = C;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway with all that being said... this code can be written way more dynamically with the idea being to give all inputs the same class name, selecting those inputs using javascript's document.getElementsByClassName() selector, then looping through the values of those. For instance:

```js
    function newDistanceInput()
    {
        var container = document.getElementById("input-container");
        var newInput = "<span><input type='number' class='DistanceInput' oninput='if (this.value < 0) {this.value = 0;} calculateDistance();' value='0' /><span onclick='this.parentNode.remove(); calculateDistance();'>remove</span><br></span>";
        container.innerHTML += newInput;
        calculateDistance();
    }

    function calculateDistance()
    {
        distInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('DistanceInput');
        totalLength = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < distInputs.length; i++)
        {
            totalLength += parseInt(distInputs[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total-length').innerText = totalLength;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button onclick="newDistanceInput();">
                Add another distance input
            </button>
            <br>
            <div id="input-container">
            </div>
            <div id="total-length">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---EDIT---

If you are referring to how to edit this post, you can go back to the top of the page, right after your question, you will see:
[image: edit button]

and the edit button is below it.
From there, in the textbox you type in, you can set up the same runable example by:
[image: circled button]

clicking the circled button.

Comment: @user14664932 , I just updated the example code to hopefully help demonstrate my idea.

Comment: is there a way to share my whole code? When I try to put all of it in, it won't let me. It's hard to get the right the answer to my question when the person trying to help can't see the whole picture. I basically have 4 switch statements, and i'm wondering if what you said about document.getElementByClassName still holds true. Thank you for your response.

Comment: What do you mean it wont let you put it all in? You can create a runable snippet in the edit section that will be super helpful for us... I will include this all in my answer.

Comment: @user14664932 if this answer is correct, would you please mark it as so?